# Not getting output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, javascript-objects, dom-events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var score=1;
    if (score==1) {
    document.write("<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>");
    }
</script>
```

My Javascript output is not coming, my IDE is telling that there is an unexpected token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same quotes here, it should be:

```
document.write('<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>');
```

Otherwise, you are early terminating the string, and the JavaScript parser attempts to parse the string (invalid JS).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the quotes("). You cannot use `"` inside another `"`

```
 document.write("<a class='next' onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

change double quotation to single like below,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var score=1;
    if (score==1) {
    document.write("<a class='next' onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>");
    }
</script>
```